# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Int32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to Query Database Context using Linq to Entities and I am getting this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Int32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Code:

```
public IEnumerable<CourseNames> GetCourseName()
{
   var course = from o in entities.UniversityCourses
                select new CourseNames
                {
                    CourseID = Convert.ToInt32(o.CourseID),
                    CourseName = o.CourseName,
                 };
   return course.ToList();
}
```

I tried like this after seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278611/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-int32-int32system-string-meth)

```
public IEnumerable<CourseNames> GetCourseName()
{
    var temp = Convert.ToInt32(o.CourseID);
    var course = from o in entities.UniversityCourses
                 select new CourseNames
                 {
                     CourseID = temp,
                     CourseName = o.CourseName,
                 };
    return course.ToList();
}
```

But it throws an error:

> "The name 'o' does not exist in the current context"

This is my code for the class `GetCourseName`

```
namespace IronwoodWeb
{
    public class CourseNames
    {
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `int.Parse(o.CourseID)`; the error is because EF didn't know how to write `Convert.ToInt32` in terms of SQL, but I think it should understand `int.Parse` .. (best would be to use the *appropriate column type* and avoid having to deal with this conversion :)

Comment: @pst using int.parse throws the same error "The name 'o' does not exist in the current context" and I can't use the same column type, it also shows error " Cannot implicitly convert type....." 
Anyway thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: Another way to get around this issue (where EF cannot translate some expression into SQL) is to run a simpler query first and at the end of it force it to populate via .ToList(). Once you have it in memory, you are no longer bound by having to convert your expressions to SQL.

Comment: @user1905332 No, that's a *different* issue (`o` is out of scope). Go back the *first* query, but replace `Convert.ToInt32` with `int.Parse`, hmm [nevermind](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/6c8892db-8df7-4174-b9b0-764dc1df82ad), it is the other way. Seems to be IEnumerable vs. IQueryable difference?

Comment: @pst No worries, the answer lazyberezovsky posted works, anyways thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: @Heather solved the problem, anyways thanks for trying to help me!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<CourseNames> GetCourseName()
{
    var courses = from o in entities.UniversityCourses
                  select new { o.CourseID, o.CourseName };

    return courses.ToList() // now we have in-memory query
                  .Select(c => new CourseNames()
                  {
                     CourseID = Convert.ToInt32(c.CourseID), // OK
                     CourseName = c.CourseName
                  });
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get str->int conversion *without* needing to force in-memory?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Thank you so much! It worked, I was trying to figure this out for more than two hours! Thanks again! :)

Comment: @pst as far as I know only there is no built-in possibility to do that conversion on server side

Comment: There is, by using an explicit conversion (see answers below)

Comment: Should be noted that it's better to use `AsEnumerable` instead to avoid creating an unneeded list in memory.

Answer (score 4):

If you dont want to materialize the query (retrieve the data) you can use cast (i.e. (int) o.CourseId). Is converted to SQL CAST AS statement.

Answer (score 3):

You could also bring back the value as a string (as it is apparently stored) and then Convert it after.

The error on 'o' being out of the context is that you are only declaring o in the Linq query and it can only be referenced in that scope.

Comment: the answer lazyberezovsky posted works, anyways thanks for trying to help me!

Answer (score -3):

Explicit conversion is simple and works: (int)o.CourseID

```
var course = from o in entities.UniversityCourses
                select new CourseNames
                {
                    CourseID = (int)o.CourseID,
                    CourseName = o.CourseName,
                 };
```

Comment: That won't even compile: CS0030: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'int'

Comment: Cast to `object` first, then `int`, then it will compile. However, then Linq to Entities still will not recognize it. Linq to SQL will, however.