# why my Linqued query is not getting executed

Tags: entity-framework, linq, c#-4.0, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have this linqued query

```
  var moreThen1dayLeavefed = (from LApp in db.LeaveApplications
                                 join Emp in db.Employees
                                on LApp.Employee equals Convert.ToInt32(Emp.EmployeeNumber)
                                 join LBrk in db.LeaveBreakups
                                on LApp.Id equals LBrk.LeaveApplication
                                 where Emp.Team == 8 && LBrk.StartDate.Year == 2015 && LBrk.StartDate.Month == 5 
                                 select new { StartDate = LBrk.StartDate.Day, EndDate = LBrk.EndDate.Day, diff = (DbFunctions.DiffDays(LBrk.StartDate, LBrk.EndDate) + 1) }).ToList();
```

it gives error 
       LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
on line 3, i.e

```
 on LApp.Employee equals Convert.ToInt32(Emp.EmployeeNumber)
```

as I am converting the string to int during inner join

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32 Converting String to Int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637985/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-int32-toint32-converting-string)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=LINQ+to+Entities+does+not+recognize+the+method+%27Int32+ToInt32%28System.String%29%27+

Comment: I am bit new to linqued queries

Comment: Please help... :).

Comment: I know it's confusing, but LINQ to Entities does not support many of the methods normally available (in LINQ to Objects for instance) even the query compiles w/o error. It's a bad practice to store numbers as strings in the database. Anyway, you can try the opposite conversion `on LApp.Employee.ToString() equals Emp.EmployeeNumber` (it's supported) and see if it works.

Comment: I tried that before and was not getting solved

Comment: Then you are out of luck. Check the links if you can find a workaround there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just saw your [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161193/how-to-store-dynamically-the-desired-value-in-my-linqued-query-variable). Your `EmployeeNumber` field seems to be filled with fixed size (5) zero left padded string representation of a number. If that's true, you can use the trick from [how to sort varchar column containing numeric values with linq lambdas to Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35506172/how-to-sort-varchar-column-containing-numeric-values-with-linq-lambdas-to-entity/35506586#35506586) to solve the issue.

Just replace

```
on LApp.Employee equals Convert.ToInt32(Emp.EmployeeNumber)
```

with

```
on DbFunctions.Right("0000" + LApp.Employee.ToString(), 5) equals Emp.EmployeeNumber
```

Comment: But LApp.Employee is a integer field

Comment: Yep - the above will convert it to string like "00001" etc.

Comment: Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: Ok, last attempt - add `ToString()` call as in the update.

Comment: getting this exception

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Both my posted code versions execute w/o any error in EF6.1.3, so you probably are using outdated EF version. I give up, good luck.

Comment: thanks brother @Ivan Stoev...thank you very much ....I just upgraded my EF 6.0 to 6.1.3 and it worked smoothly..... :)