# how to store dynamically the desired value in my linqued query variable

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have this query

```
  var empno = (from LApp in db.Employees
                    select new { LApp.EmployeeNumber }).ToList();
```

when executed I have this in empno

[image]

what I want is to trim the starting zeros and store it in empno

i.e  {EmployeeNumber="2"} and so on...
How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TrimStart()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to remove leading zeros, something like this :

```
var empno = (from LApp in db.Employees
             select new { EmployeeNumber = LApp.EmployeeNumber.TrimStart('0') }
            ).ToList();
```

I have no idea if `TrimStart()` can be translated to SQL, you might need `AsEnumerable()` if `TrimStart()` turned out not supported.